# Can't convert gltf with forge-convert-utils

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I created the file "convert.js" with an example code from the library with the command
run ('urn of your model', 'path / to / output / folder'); to get the model in gltf. When I run 'node convert.js' in the console, I get an error.

My steps: 1.created project 2.npm install forge-convert-utils 3.npm install dotenv. 4.npm install forge-server-utils 5.create file convert.js, folder 'folder' and config file .env 6.
node convert.js

convert.js

```
const { ModelDerivativeClient, ManifestHelper } = require('forge-server-utils');
const { SvfReader, GltfWriter } = require('forge-convert-utils');
require('dotenv/config');
const { FORGE_CLIENT_ID, FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET } = process.env;

async function run (urn, outputDir) {
    const auth = { client_id: FORGE_CLIENT_ID, client_secret: FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET };
    try{
        const modelDerivativeClient = new ModelDerivativeClient(auth);
        // crashed
        const helper = new ManifestHelper(await modelDerivativeClient.getManifest(urn));
        const derivatives = helper.search({ type: 'resource', role: 'graphics' });
        const writer = new GltfWriter(outputDir);
        for (const derivative of derivatives.filter(d => d.mime === 'application/autodesk-svf')) {
            const reader = await SvfReader.FromDerivativeService(urn, derivative.guid, auth);
            const svf = await reader.read();
            writer.write(svf);
        }
        writer.close();
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}


run('dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6b3QwanRnamF3aGFoaWV0bDljYjkyZmNtZWZlcGkyZ2YtY3VzdG9tZXItZGVtb3MvQVMlMjBNQURFJTIwTUFJTSUyMFNIQUJBWkktMTkwMjE5LmR3Zw==', 'folder');
```

C:\Users\Bioro\WebstormProjects\svf-to-gltf\forge-convert-custom>node convert.js
(node:12108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 404

```
at createError (C:\Users\Bioro\WebstormProjects\svf-to-gltf\forge-convert-custom\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
at settle (C:\Users\Bioro\WebstormProjects\svf-to-gltf\forge-convert-custom\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\Bioro\WebstormProjects\svf-to-gltf\forge-convert-custom\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:237:11)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:194:15)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1125:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

(node:12108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not h
andled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)

(node:12108) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace doesn't say much, just that something in Forge is missing. Try wrapping the inside of your `run` function in a `try-catch` block to get more information out of the exception being thrown.

Note that the `forge-convert-utils` library assumes that the URN has already been translated with Model Derivative service (using the [POST job](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST)).

Comment: urn is working, in postman i can get manifest response - link with response photo https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JJ819YKYY1Yq87P6X8kkkJgXKO7Qf1vl/view?usp=sharing .  All error in text file (404 error) - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fOXGrU4qGt5ZZtXw2Uz356anlKTXkJfS/view?usp=sharing                                                                                                                                    But i can't get manifest in postman with token, which creates forge-convert-utils.

Comment: Thanks, so the call to `await modelDerivativeClient.getManifest(urn)` should work fine, and the 404 is probably coming from somewhere else. Again, please try and step through the code or wrap it in a `try-catch` block to see which request specifically fails.

Comment: Program crashed after code line `const modelDerivativeClient = new ModelDerivativeClient(auth);` This error [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BJ7cQSAjMuLEEeByFDEp2gm3_FUwzYsD/view?usp=sharing)  It happens during get manifest request.

Comment: That's really strange... Are you using the same Forge credentials when running the converter as in Postman? The converter uses the scope "data:read" when requesting the manifest which should be (according to https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET) fine. If you're still getting 404s, would you mind sharing your Forge credentials with us via forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com? I could then investigate on my end and see what's going on there.